# MATALB Kinnect sensor depth image(Too Dark)

Tags: image, matlab, kinect, depth

I am using Kinect2 with Matlab; however, the depth images shown in the video stream are much brighter than when I saved it in Matlab?
do you know the solution for this problem

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used mat2gray and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you should provide the code that you are using at the moment so we can see where you  are going wrong.. this is a generic advice for posting on any forum; to provide with all your information, so others can help.
2. If you use the histogram to check your depth values, you will see that the image is a uint8 image with values from 0 to 255. And since the depth distances are scaled to grayscale value, the values are scaled to new values and using imshow, will not provide enough contrast.
3. An easy workaround for displaying images is to use any type of
   histogram equalization such as

   ```
   figure(1); 
   C= adapthisteq(A, 'clipLimit',0.02,'Distribution','rayleigh'); 
   imshow(C);
   ```

   The image will be contrast adjusted for display.

Comment: Thank you for your help ; I used mat2gray and it solved the problem.